# How do i have specific numbers display based on what i clicked on for forloop c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out on how to add a specific amount from a listbox based on the number i clicked.I have a listbox with numbers from 1 day to 14 days.When I click for example 7 days it will be displayed on my 2nd listbox from 1 to 7 days.

1st listbox

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    listBox1.Items.Add(1+" Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(2 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(3 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(4 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(5 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(6 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(7 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(8 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(9 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(10 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(11 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(12 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(13 + " Days(s)");
    listBox1.Items.Add(14 + " Days(s)"); 
}
```

2nd listbox

```
private void listBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
        {
            listBox1.SetSelected(i, true);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking `Listbox.SelectedIndex` like the following:

```
private void listBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   for (int i = 0; i <= listBox1.SelectedIndex; i++)
   {
      listBox3.Items.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
   }
}
```

Check [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex(v=vs.110).aspx).